# Node.js making Request for Each line of Input File and Writing Response to Output Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request

I am attempting to read the input file HA.csv and for each line I want to make a request (api.getFundamentals) and write the output to a file. The code below works only for one line of the csv. I am thinking this maybe a synchronisation problem.

```
function readLines({ input }) {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({ input });
  rl.on("line", line => {
    if(line != "Code") {
      api.getFundamentals(line).then(result => reader.writeFile(JSON.stringify(result), line + ".txt"))
    }
  });
}
const input = fs.createReadStream("HA.csv");
(async () => {
  for await (const line of readLines({ input })) {
  }
})();


//From another class
module.exports.writeFile = (data, filename) => {
    fs.writeFile(filename, data, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
    console.log(line);
};
```

As I said, this solution works for just one line of the input csv. The console displays the following, multiple times.

```
(node:25574) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: line is not defined
    at Object.module.exports.writeFile (/Users/node-stock/reader.js:44:17)
    at api.getFundamentals.then.result (/Users/node-stock/server.js:48:55)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:25574) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the cause of the error on your own by adding catch block.

Please refer to the code below.

```js
function readLines({ input }) {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({ input });
  rl.on("line", line => {
    if(line != "Code") {
      api.getFundamentals(line)
      .then(result => reader.writeFile(JSON.stringify(result), line + ".txt"))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
  });
}

const input = fs.createReadStream("HA.csv");

(async () => {
  try {
      for await (const line of readLines({ input })) {}
  } catch(err){
      console.error(err);
  }
})();


//From another class
module.exports.writeFile = (data, filename) => {
    fs.writeFile(filename, data, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
    console.log(line);
};
```